# Why is Firestore ignoring the 'array_contains' part of this compound query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

The following query is returning results for ("flag","==","someFlag") as if the array_contains part of the query doesn't exist:

```
myRef
  .collection('someCollection')
  .where("flag","==","someFlag")
  .where("folders","array_contains","test string")
  .get()
```

My expectation was that this query would produce an error in the console with a link to create a composite index for the two fields in the query. I can create the index myself, but didn't want to do so without trying to fully understand what's going on.

**EDIT:**
This gibberish query has the same effect (returns results for "flag == someFlag"). Shouldn't it throw an error?

```
myRef
  .collection('someCollection')
  .where("flag","==","someFlag")
  .where("asdf","asdf","asdf")
  .get()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why doesn't the query fail and line up with the stated expectation? I'll edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make the assumption you are using the Web SDK. Note that the syntax is

```
.where("folders","array-contains","test string")
```

and not

```
.where("folders","array_contains","test string")
```